# Selecting items from a python dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

Given the following data structure:

```
   data = {'NameValues':[
          {'Name':'Field 1', 'Values':['Data 1']}, 
          {'Name':'Field 2', 'Values':['Data 2']}, 
          {'Name':'Field 3', 'Values':['Data 3']}, 
          {'Name':'Field 4', 'Values':['Data 4']}, 
          {'Name':'Field 5', 'Values':['Data 5']}
          ]}
```

How can find by name and get the value of an element? e.g. get the values for Field 3.

In Ruby I would use this:

```
p hash['NameValues'].find{ |h| h['Name'] == 'Field 3'}['Values']
#=> ["Data 3"]
```

This iterates through the NameValues array until a matching element is found. I can then get the Values from the returned element.

Regards

Comment: `[v['Values'] for v in data['NameValues'] if v['Name'] == 'Field 3']`

Comment: +1 to the comment above, but is there any reason for the structure to be like that and not {"NameValues": {"Field 1": ["Data 1"], "Field 2": ["Data 2"]...} ?

Comment: @PedroWerneck a guess is, this is some sort of json.

Comment: I'm getting the data via an API and thats the way it is - that bits out of my control.

Comment: Nice and clean works perfectly - thanks.

Answer (score 4):

For your iteration requirement, a generator is more appropriate:

```
>>> data = {'NameValues':[
...           {'Name':'Field 1', 'Values':['Data 1']},
...           {'Name':'Field 2', 'Values':['Data 2']},
...           {'Name':'Field 3', 'Values':['Data 3']},
...           {'Name':'Field 4', 'Values':['Data 4']},
...           {'Name':'Field 5', 'Values':['Data 5']}
...           ]}
>>> i = (v['Values'] for v in data['NameValues'] if v['Name'] == 'Field 3')
>>> next(i)
['Data 3']
```

You will get a `StopIteration` exception when there are no more elements that match your condition.

Comment: Could you elaborate more about the use of generator here? It is obviously a good solution, but for a future readers it would bemore valuable to add some explanation

Comment: Unlike a list comprehention, a generator is only executed when it is consumed; so assuming data was a large collection, a list comprehension would create a large in memory list. In this specific case, a list comprehension would also generate an unnecessary outer (enclosing) list.

Comment: Well I do know that, I was just suggesting that it would be valuable to add it to your answer for future reference

Answer (score 1):

```
for i in data['NameValues']:
    if i['name'] == 'Field 3':
        value = i['values']
# use value here
```

I'm a complete newbie at using Python though, someone will probably give a better answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can use similer syntax to:

```
p hash['NameValues'].find{ |h| h['Name'] == 'Field 3'}['Values']
#=> ["Data 3"]
```

with [`filter`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#filter):

```
>>> data = {'NameValues':[
...           {'Name':'Field 1', 'Values':['Data 1']},
...           {'Name':'Field 2', 'Values':['Data 2']},
...           {'Name':'Field 3', 'Values':['Data 3']},
...           {'Name':'Field 4', 'Values':['Data 4']},
...           {'Name':'Field 5', 'Values':['Data 5']}
...           ]}
>>>
>>> filter(lambda h: h['Name'] == 'Field 3', data['NameValues'])[0]['Values']
['Data 3']
>>>
```

or if you use Python 3:

```
>>> list(filter(lambda h: h['Name'] == 'Field 3', data['NameValues']))[0]['Values']
```

Comment: Not sure since I am not that experienced in Python, but when I run your code in Python 3.3.2 I get the following error: `TypeError: 'filter' object is not subscriptable`.

Comment: @Qantas94Heavy Thank you for replay, it looks that there is a different in `filter` return type between 2 and 3.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a list of all values that meet your criteria `f` in some container `C` by

```
l = [ e(v) for v in C if f(v) ]
```

where `e` is some extracting function.

In your particular case you could use `C:=data'NameValues'`,`e(v):=v['values']`, `f(v):=v['Name']=='Field 3'`

```
l = [ v['Values'] for v in data['NameValues'] if v['Name'] == 'Field 3' ]
print l
```

and if you are only interested in the first occurence

```
l = [ v['Values'] for v in data['NameValues'] if v['Name'] == 'Field 3' ][0]
print l
```